# Update Query - Setting new_field = existing_field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an access 2007 table with about 3000 records, to which I have added
an additional field containing a numeric value.

I would like to run an update query on the table, going through all the
records in my table and setting the value of this new field to the same as
an existing field in the table.

is there a quick way to do this in the query builder? Or will I have to create VBA
code to loop through the table and run an update statement for each
row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update table
set newfield = existingfield
```

should set the value of new field in all records to that of the existing field